# How to redirect STDERR to STDOUT in the context of a Ruby program maintaning portability?

Tags: ruby, redirect, stdout, portability, stderr

I would like to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` in all `%x{}` statement. I used in the past `%x{program 2>&1}` but I think it won't work on Windows or other systems. How to do it in a more rubysh way to maintain compatibility and portability, I want to make work my script on every possible system.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from both `stderr` and `stdout`, for example.

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3('ls error') do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wt|
  STDOUT.write(stdout.read)
  STDOUT.write(stderr.read)
end
```

Running it.

```
$ ruby example.rb 2>/dev/null
ls: error: No such file or directory
```